# matlab's im2bw results in dark/light blue

Tags: matlab

When I grab a picture from my webcam and use the function im2bw, it results in a light- and dark blue image instead of black and white. What is causing this?

I'm on R2011a for Linux

Comment: are you using `colormap` command anywhere?

Comment: Are you using `image` function to show the image? How it looks with `imshow`? How about it you save it and open outside MATLAB?

Comment: That did it! I was indeed using image to show the image, imshow displays it in black and white, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are possibly converting indexed image. Try to run im2bw with map argument.

```
BW = im2bw(X, map, level)
```

You get map, when you read the image as

```
[X, map] = imread(file);
```

---

**EDIT**

According to OP the answer was actually in my comment to the question, not here. To display the image the function [IMAGE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) was used. This function uses JET colormap and does not scale the image, this is why it usually show image in blueish color. To display image It's better to use [IMSHOW](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) function from Image Processing Toolbox.

Comment: I am using images captured from my webcam, so not from a file. But the solution was using imshow instead of image to display the image. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

BTW:
If one doesn't have an image processing toolbox:

```
image(uint8(repmat(picture, [1,1,3])));
axis image
```

should help.